# Как создать двумерный массив чисел Big integer на Kotlin?

Tags: массивы, kotlin, коллекции

Необходимо создать массив 28827050410 на 35165045587. Пробовал искать, но на счет kotlin, и его двумерных массивов нашел очень мало, нашел вот такой вариант:

```
var array = Array(Line){IntArray(Column,{it * 0})}
```

Но он тоже мне не подходит потому что принимает, значения int в качестве аргументов.

P.S. Можно поместить в коллекцию.

Comment: Использовать Long?

Comment: Каким образом, можешь рассказать по подробнее ? Или скинуть какую либо ссылку, где про это можно почитать ?

Comment: `28827050410 на 35165045587` это размеры массива?

Comment: Да, это размеры

Comment: уверены, что оперативной памяти хватит?

Comment: 32гб DDR3, думаю хватит

Comment: Не думаю, что стандартные массивы способны на такое. Придется что-то свое писать поверх.
https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-array/size.html

Comment: Спасибо за ответ

Comment: 28827050410 * 35165045587 * 4 (int) байт = 3 776 343 695 098 гб, точно хватит?

Comment: @АнтонЧелышков , для общего развития, поделитесь - это где такое может применяться?